# Counting most common edge from tuples in a list

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples:
`list = [("a","b"), ("a","c"), ("a","d"), ("b","d"), ("c","d")......]`

these represent edges between nodes and are undirected, so if `("a","b")` exists, `("b","a")` will not exist.
I want to be able to find the node with the most number of edges as well as return the number of edges that the maximum has. I'm not quite sure how to approach this problem. Also, the data within the tuples are strings.

In regards to the "return the number of edges", in the case of
`list = [("a","b"), ("a","c"), ("a","d"), ("b","d"), ("c","d")]` I would get the output of `a` as the node with most edges, and somehow have the count of the number of edges, so 3 in that case. I suppose you could also just count how many times `a` appears within the list, but I'm really new to dealing with tuples so I'm not sure how that would work.

Comment: What do you mean with this "as well as return the number of edges that maximum has" ?

Comment: The best approach to start is *any* approach; you can always fix your code later.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this to count the number of edges associated with a node:

```
node_names = ["a", "b", "c", "d"] # possibly more
counter = {} # initialize counter dictionary
for node_name in node_names:
    num_edges = len([i for i in list if node_name in i]) # count number of matches
    counter[node_name] = num_edges # add value to dictionary
print(counter["a"]) # 3
```

Answer (score 1):

[collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) along with [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) would be very handy for your usecase

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

my_list = [("a","b"), ("a","c"), ("a","d"), ("b","d"), ("c","d")]

counter = Counter(chain.from_iterable(my_list))

print(counter.most_common(1))
```

```
[('a', 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty but I got something to sort of work -

```
edge_count = [0] * len(test_nodes2)
node_ids = []

for i in range(len(test_nodes2)):
    node_ids.append(test_nodes2[i][0])
    
    for k in range(len(test_edges)):

        if (test_nodes2[i][0] in test_edges[k][0] or test_nodes2[i][0] in test_edges[k][1]):
            edge_count[i] = edge_count[i]+1
    

    pass


max_count = max(edge_count)
j=0
M=[]

for i in range(len(edge_count)):
    if edge_count[i]==max_count:
        M.append(j)
    
    j+=1
```

Still not completely solved, but most of the elements are out - huge thanks to Leonard and Niel Godfrey Ponciano (unfortunately I can't use libraries, but it was an awesome find!) - If any sees the nested for loops and can help get rid of them would be awesome - but I'm ok with ugly code that works.